# Getting strange answer from PN532 with raspberry pi

Tags: java, serial-port, raspberry-pi

after I send command to adafruit PN532:

```
00 00 ff 03 fd d4 14 01 17 00
```

I get answer:

```
00 00 C3 BF 00 C3 BF 00 00 00 C3 BF 02 C3 BE C3 95 15 16 00
```

Instead of:

```
00 00 ff 00 ff 00 00 00 ff 02 fe d5 15 16 00
```

I am communicating with PN532 using uart through serial port "/dev/ttyAMA0"
I have code in Java. Reading from GPIO using pi4j.
Do you know why I am getting this kind of mishmashed answer?

Here is my code:

```
public class NFCapp {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] SAMConfiguration = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x03, (byte) 0xfd, (byte) 0xd4, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0x00};
    byte[] wakeUP = {(byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00};
    final byte[] ack = {(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0x00};
    final Serial serial = SerialFactory.createInstance();
    try {


        serial.open("/dev/ttyAMA0", 115200);
        serial.addListener(new SerialDataListener() {
            @Override
            public void dataReceived(SerialDataEvent event) {
                String data = event.getData();
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                byte[] array = data.getBytes();

                System.out.println("Read: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    System.out.printf("%02X ", array[i]);
                }
                serial.write(ack);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Port Opened: " + serial.isOpen() + " ");
        serial.write(wakeUP);
        System.out.print("Write: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < SAMConfiguration.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%02X ", SAMConfiguration[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        serial.write(SAMConfiguration);

        for (;;) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        serial.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I've implemented a more thorough solution for this (see it at https://github.com/hsilomedus/hands-on-raspi/tree/nfc-serial/src) by re-implementing https://github.com/elechouse/PN532 but with pi4j and java. However, I can't get ANY response out of the module (http://imall.iteadstudio.com/prototyping/basic-module/im130625002.html). With arduino works, but with raspi no. Everything connected (tx to rx, rx to tx, gnd, voltage with even 5 and 3.3V) but no response whatsoever. any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: are you sure that you have your serial port freed?
(http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/12/free-your-raspberry-pi-serial-port/) also try tx to tx/rx to rx connection every manufacturer is marking those port differently.

Comment: Raspi to arduino via serial port works (with voltage divider from arduino to raspi). Arduino to PN532 via serial port works. RasPi to PN532 doesn't want to start at all. And yes, I've freed the serial port. I previously made another serial implementation with pi4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want bytes, but you are reading a string and converting it to bytes.  Unfortunately, it looks like in the process your data is getting UTF-8 encoded.  For example 0xC3BF is the UTF-8 encoding of "\u00FF" unicode character.  Also unfortunately, the only way to get data from [SerialDataEvent](http://pi4j.com/apidocs/com/pi4j/io/serial/SerialDataEvent.html) is as a string.  How the original bytes were decoded into a string depend on which string constructor was called.  Looks like UTF-16 (probably big endian), so you might try this:

```
byte[] array = data.getBytes("UTF-16");
```

This is hacky, the real fix is to improve Pi4J and add a SerialDataEvent.getBytes() method.  I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
data.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

(data.getBytes("UTF-16") was returning 2 bytes per byte read, with 0x00 in the second byte)